# Bash Redirect to a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to redirect output of a command to a file. The command I am using (zypper) downloads packages from the internet. The command I am using is

zypper -x -n in geany >> log.txt

The command gradually prints output to the console. The problem I am facing is that the above command writes the command output all at once after the command finishes executing. How do I redirect the bash output as I get it onto the terminal, rather than writing all the command output at the end.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/294218/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-without-buffering-on-unix-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

&>>FILE COMMAND

will append the output of COMMAND to FILE

In your case

```
&>>log.txt zypper -x -n in geany
```

If you want to pipe a command through a filter, you must assure that the command outputs to standard output (file descriptor 1) -- if it outputs to standard error (file descriptor 2), you have to redirect the 2 to 1 before the pipe. Take into account that only stdout passed through a pipe.

So you have to do so:

```
2>&1 COMMAND | FILTER
```

If you want to grep the output and in the same keep it into a log file, you have to duplicate it with `tee`, and use a filter like  `... | tee log-file | grep options`

Comment: how can we use a pipe with the zypper command here? I also need to use a grep there.

Comment: the command i am now trying is 
2&>1 /var/log/oneclick.log zypper -x -n in geany | grep -o "percent=\"[0-9]*\""

this doesnt seem to be doing anything

Comment: 2>&1 zypper -x -n in geany | FILTER is what you want

Comment: Sorry, I wrote by mistake "2&>1" instead of 2>&1. It created a file called "1".

Comment: Now i tried

2>&1 zypper -x -n in geany | tee /var/log/oneclick.log | grep -o "percent=\"[0-9]*\""

This writes the file at the end, and without the grep output

Comment: This command does so: creates the ouput from `zypper`, then save it in `log` and in the same time it outputs it, and the output will be grepped. The log file contains the direct ouput of zypper, and the final output on the screen will be grepped. If you want the log to be grepped, you need to reverse `tee` and `grep`.

Comment: 2>&1 zypper -x -n in geany | grep -o "percent=\"[0-9]*\"" | tee /var/log/oneclick.log will save the filtered output in log file, and displays the filtered output. This is what you want ?

Comment: The above command is still writing at the end of the zypper command execution. I want it to write the output whenever output from zypper is available(after filtering)

Comment: Ah, I understand. You need to modify the buffer size of the pipe! zypper outputs less than the pipe buffer size, and this is why it happens at the end. you need to low the size for the pipe to send its input to output before it finished.

Comment: 2>&1 zypper -x -n in geany | grep -o --line-buffered "percent=\"[0-9]*\"" | tee /var/log/oneclick.log

adding the --line-buffered option to grep seems to do the trick :)

Answer (score 5):

Not with bash itself, but via the `tee` command:

```
zipper -x -n in geany | tee log.txt
```